# Как дополнить uri, содержащий в себе неполный url, полученный из textview (Android)?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-intent, uri

Захотелось мне написать нечто вроде примитивного браузера.

Вот код:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    Button btnGo;
    Button btnBack;
    EditText etURL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
        btnBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBack);
        etURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etURL);
        btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = etURL.getText().toString();
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        }
        );

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Соответственно если в TextView вводить неполный url, а например: google.ru или www.google.ru, то ничего не происходит. Отрабатывает например если ввести http://ya.ru. Подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема ?

**Обновление**

Извиняюсь за свою невнимательность. В строке `mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());` исправил `mWebView` на `WebView`. Не отрабатывало потому, что в private class `MyWebViewClient` я указываю `WebViewClient`, а не `mWebViewClien` )) Запутался в общем.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

```
btnGo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String url = etURL.getText().toString();
                if (!url.startsWith("http://")) {
                   url="http://" + url;
                }
                mWebView.loadUrl(url);
            }
        }
```

Следует так же добавить, что проверка тут осуществляется очень примитивная. Данная проверка лишь показывает, куда надо смотреть, но не полностью проверяет URL

Comment: Полагаю таким образом часть http присоединится к концу адреса, а не к началу

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'startWith(java.Lang.string)'

Comment: @Madcap [String.startsWith()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String))

Comment: Werder прав, правильно будет : `url = "http://"+url`

Comment: Да, совершенно правильно. Сейчас подредактирую ответ.

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало. Однако не все ссылки открываются в WebView, некоторые не проходят. Я подозреваю, что ответ кроется в редиректе со стороны сайта. С этим можно что-то сделать ?